# Is there any way to convert Log file to CSV using python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scripting, export-to-csv

I have a log file in the .txt format and wanted to convert it into. CSV format with header is there any way I can store data from .txt to.csv in a specific format.
I have attached both the log file and require CSV file.
Link to log file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10U4_jQrioNEF7Qb3uMruQleWDwWHNcE1/view?usp=sharing)

```
New Data Received at : 2022-06-07 17:19:42.714867                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                    
$   1   SECURE  SAM1.0  DT  H   8.64337E+14 TN04E1234   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   BSNL    1   1   15  0   0   W   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   59*
$   1   SECURE  SAM1.0  DT  H   8.64337E+14 TN04E1234   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   BSNL    1   1   15  0   0   W   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   60*
$   1   SECURE  SAM1.0  DT  H   8.64337E+14 TN04E1234   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   BSNL    1   1   15  0   0   W   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   61*
$   1   SECURE  SAM1.0  DT  L   8.64337E+14 TN04E1234   0   6012080 50  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   BSNL    1   1   15  0   0   W   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   88*
$   1   SECURE  SAM1.0  DT  L   8.64337E+14 TN04E1234   0   6012080 100 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   BSNL    1   1   15  0   0   W   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   5   85*
$   1   SECURE  SAM1.0  DT  L   8.64337E+14 TN04E1234   0   6012080 110 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   BSNL    1   1   15  0   0   W   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   6   87*
```

Require format in .CSV file
link of sample CSV file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yq7Sjp9-B2hUkeUAMP7bMT7UtxkT2sOd/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Yes - There are several ways to do this. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes - You can ignore New Data received line and replace whitespace with comma or any separator.

Comment: @AlbertWinestein
I have tried reading from file and export it to csv using pandas

Comment: @DigviJayPatil Can you help me with any tutorial link if available?

Comment: @PradipWaghela In that case, please show the code you're having trouble with

Comment: @PradipWaghela   Read file line by line.  While reading get line string and replace whitespace with comma and simultaneously write modified line string into CSV file.  Here you have to open two file one text file for reading and CSV file for writing.

Comment: @PradipWaghela It is very easy to break log file into separate columns if the fields are separated with tab `\t` . Looks like they are separated with tabs. So split the lines with tab character. You will have to work around to remove lines of description ( lines like `New Data Received at : 2022-06-07 17:19:42.714867 ` ). After that its easy to assign data into a pandas DF

Comment: @AlbertWinestein
@AlbertWinestein
Here is my code
`import pandas as pd`
`log = pd.read_csv("log_file.txt")`
`data=pd.DataFrame(log)`
`print(data)`
`log.to_csv("Logfile.csv",index=False,sep=",")`
Here is output file [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CeiVcMW62eAgCTuJSK102ngrgA-ta1ay/view?usp=sharing)
Now I wanted to arrange it order with header like this file [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yq7Sjp9-B2hUkeUAMP7bMT7UtxkT2sOd/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @KavinduRavishka can you provide sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll use the small log file part provided in your question.

First we need to remove descriptions.
I assume that all entries are started with `$`. And in your sample log, fields are separated with spaces. So I split lines with spaces.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

file = open('log.txt','r')
s= file.read()
lines = s.split('\n')

filt_lines =[]
for l in lines:
    if l.startswith('$'):
        filt_lines.append(l)

array = [l.split() for l in filt_lines]

log_df = pd.DataFrame(array)

# And write it to csv
log_df.to_csv("log.csv")
```

The result is

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ...     28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37
0   $   1   SECURE  SAM1.0  DT  H   8.64337E+14     TN04E1234   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   59*
1   $   1   SECURE  SAM1.0  DT  H   8.64337E+14     TN04E1234   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   60*
2   $   1   SECURE  SAM1.0  DT  H   8.64337E+14     TN04E1234   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   61*
3   $   1   SECURE  SAM1.0  DT  L   8.64337E+14     TN04E1234   0   6012080     ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   88*
4   $   1   SECURE  SAM1.0  DT  L   8.64337E+14     TN04E1234   0   6012080     ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   5   85*
5   $   1   SECURE  SAM1.0  DT  L   8.64337E+14     TN04E1234   0   6012080     ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   6   87*
```

There is some work you need to do to the log_df to get the required csv file before writing it in to csv. There are some columns in required csv example which are not in the log file. You have to check them and manually create those columns. Later add index to the dataframe and write.